# Find the most recently created file in the directories and sub-directories using PowerShell or Windows Batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have 30 different folders which I need to iterate thru, within each one there’s a Log folder and inside that, are the text files. I’m after the latest one, which I need to copy to the new location with the preferred name (E.G. **2020-03-28.txt.FolderServerName1**, where appended variable FolderServerName1, identifies from which server it came from)

```
set source="\\ServerName\LogFolders" 
set target=" C:\Data\CopiedLogFiles"
```

```
FolderServerName1
    Log
        2020-03-26.txt
        2020-03-27.txt
        **2020-03-28.txt**
FolderServerName2
    Log
        2020-03-26.txt
        2020-03-27.txt
        **2020-03-28.txt**
FolderServerName3
    Log
        2020-03-26.txt
        2020-03-27.txt
        **2020-03-28.txt**
```

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120801-00/?p=6993

The post above is very useful, but I think I need another nested loop within, which I'm struggling with syntactically.

Thank You so much!

Comment: Hi Russ, can you please copy-paste what you are using out of the post and what you have tried to add the nested loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file copying task can be done with:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /D %%I in ("\\ServerName\LogFolders\*") do (
    set "CopyDone="
    for /F "delims=" %%J in ('dir "%%I\Log\20??-??-??.txt" /A-D-H /B /O-N 2^>nul') do if not defined CopyDone (
        copy /Y "%%I\Log\%%J" "C:\Data\CopiedLogFiles\%%~nJ_%%~nxI%%~xJ" >nul
        set "CopyDone=1"
    )
)
endlocal
```

For each non-hidden subdirectory in `\\ServerName\LogFolders` the outer **FOR** loop first deletes the environment variable `CopyDone` and runs one more **FOR** loop.

The inner **FOR** loop starts in background one more command process using `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line enclosed in `'` as additional commands. So executed with Windows installed into `C:\Windows` is in background for example:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir "\\ServerName\LogFolders\FolderServerName1\Log\20??-??-??.txt" /A-D /B /O-N 2>nul
```

The command **DIR** searches in specified directory

- only for non-hidden files because of option `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden)
- with a file name matching the wildcard pattern `20??-??-??.txt`
- and outputs in bare format because of option `/B` just each file name with extension without path
- ordered reverse by name because of option `/O-N`
- to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) of the background command process.

The reverse output sorted alphabetically by name results for the log file names that `2020-03-28.txt` is output on first line, `2020-03-27.txt` on second line and `2020-03-26.txt` on third line.

It could be that the subdirectory `Log` does not exist at all or does not contain any file matching the wildcard pattern. In this case command **DIR** outputs an error message to handle **STDERR** (standard error) which is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL** with `2>nul`.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The command process processing the batch file captures everything written to handle **STDOUT** of background command process and **FOR** processes this captured output line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself.

**FOR** ignores empty lines which do not occur here.

**FOR** would split up by default each line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab character as string delimiters, would next look if first substring starts with default end of line character `;` in which case the line would be also ignored and otherwise would assign just first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable. It would be possible here to use this default line processing behavior as the file names do not contain a space character. But it is nevertheless better to disable line splitting behavior by using `delims=` to define an empty list of string delimiters.

So the inner **FOR** assigns on first loop iteration the file name of newest file according to international formatted date in file name to loop variable `J` and runs the command **IF**.

On first loop iteration of the inner **FOR** loop the environment variable `CopyDone` is always not defined as made sure on the command line above and so the **IF** condition is true.

For that reason the file is copied which means for first folder `FolderServerName1` that the executed **COPY** command is:

```
copy /Y "\\ServerName\LogFolders\FolderServerName1\Log\2020-03-28.txt" "C:\Data\CopiedLogFiles\2020-03-28_FolderServerName1.txt" >nul
```

The target file name is modified from requested `2020-03-28.txt.FolderServerName1` to `2020-03-28_FolderServerName1.txt`. It is in general better to use a dot in the name of a file just once as separator between file name and file extension and keep the file extension at end of the name of the file to be able to open the file with a double click.

The environment variable `CopyDone` is defined with a value after the file copying is done without verification on success. The string value assigned to environment variable `CopyDone` does not matter in this case.

The inner **FOR** continues processing the captured lines by assigning one file name after the other to loop variable `J` and running the **IF** condition. But this condition is not true for any other file name than the first file name.
To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does work and pretty elegant, I've checked. But I already came up with something on my own. 

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /AD/B/X \\ServerName\LogFolders\') 
do for /f %%i in ('dir \\ServerName\LogFolders\%%G\Log\*.* /b/a-d/od/t:c') 
do copy /y \\ServerName\LogFolders\%%G\Log\%%i \\Data\CopiedLogFiles\%%G_%%i